# Как в Yii2 в GridView делать поиск по полям используя метод POST

Tags: php, yii2, gridview, pjax, kartik

Использую в Yii2 виджет GridView от kartik, но это не главное. Таблица содержит большое количество полей и у каждого поля есть фильтр. Данные обновляются через PJAX.

```
            <?php Pjax::begin([
                'timeout' => 100000,
                'id'=>'pjax-container-table',
            ]); ?>
            <?=
            GridView::widget([
                'id'  => 'pjax-container-table',
                'dataProvider'  => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel'   => $searchModel,
                'layout'        => "{items} {pager}",
                'columns' => $gridColumns,
            ]);
            ?>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Проблема в том, что устанавливая значения фильтров, данные почему-то передаются методом GET, что выглядит очень некрасиво (полей много). Как сделать так, чтобы данные передавались методом POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опцию method=>POST нужно добавить

```
 <?php Pjax::begin([
                    'timeout' => 100000,
                    'id'=>'pjax-container-table',
                    'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']
                ]); ?>
```

И если вы используете dataprovider, вам нужно немного изменить контроллер вывода:
Было:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

Станет:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

**Способ 2:**
Добавьте в опции pjax::begin значение 'enablePushState' => false, по идее эта опция не позволяет обновлять url, но метод по-прежнему останется GET

```
<?php Pjax::begin([
                    'timeout' => 100000,
                    'id'=>'pjax-container-table',
                    'enablePushState' => false
                ]); ?>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Исчерпывающий ответ!